# What is a Event Driven non blocking IO model in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I don't understand what is the real difference between the codes:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('/file.md', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const data = fs.readFileSync('/file.md');
```

Please somebody tell me what is going on here in simplified way.

Comment: The first is an example of non-blocking I/O.  The second is an example of blocking I/O.  For files, node.js can do either one.  For things like networking, only non-blocking I/O exists.  Your question is very broad (it could take dozens of pages of responses to fully explain the whole concept which is generally considered too broad for stackoverflow).  I there a more specific question you can edit this to address?

Comment: Basically in your first example, readFile is called and javascript moves on to the next line (if there is one) whether readFile is done or not (non-blocking). When the readFile call is done it will fire an event and the code in the (err, data) will run. In your second example when readFileSync is called, javascript will wait for it to complete before it moves on to the next line of code (blocking). If you really want to understand I will encourage you to watch this video on the event loop: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take look at this example

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');

var app = express.createServer(express.logger());

app.get('/readFile', function(request, response) {
    fs.readFile('data.txt', function(err, data){
        response.send(data);
    });
});


app.get('/readFileSync', function(request, response) {
   let data =  fs.readFileSync('data.txt');
});

response.send(data);
```

fs.readFile takes a call back which calls response.send. If you simply replace that with fs.readFileSync, you need to be aware it does not take a callback so your callback which calls response.send will never get called and therefore the response will never end and it will timeout.

You need to show your readFileSync code if you're not simply replacing readFile with readFileSync.

Also, just so you're aware, you should never call readFileSync in a node express/webserver since it will tie up the single thread loop while I/O is performed. You want the node loop to process other requests until the I/O completes and your callback handling code can run. Though you can use the promise to handle this.

And from v10.0.0 The callback parameter is no longer optional for readFile. Not passing it will throw a TypeError at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

In few words the difference is that the first snippet is asynchronous.

The real difference is when the code after the snippets get executed.

So if you try to execute:

```
const fs = require('fs');
console.log('preparing...');
fs.readFile('/file.md', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('I am sure that the data is read!');
  console.log(data);
});

console.log('Not sure if the data is here... ');
```

you'll see (if the file is big enough):

```
preparing...
Not sure if the data is here...
I am sure that the data is read!
$data
```

In the other case (the `readFileSync`), the data will be there (unless of errors).

Comment: Your `console.log(data)` will never show the data here.  You have to put that inside the callback function to see the data.  In fact, the way you have it written here, that will be a script error because the `data` variable is not in scope.